# Multiple line charts using Dash and Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a multiple line charts where I have one line for each 'Machine' and 'Time' on X axis. However I tried a lot of combinations to generate X and Y label. The closest I got from expected result is the chart below.

- All advises are welcome.

This is the dataframe:

```
df3:
Machine Units Pruduced  Time
K2K02   1900            15
K2K03   311             15
K2K01   5230            17
K2K02   1096            12
K2K03   1082            11
K2K07   587             17...
```

So I am grouping and unstacking to prepare df to plot the graph.

```
fdr = dff3.groupby(['Time', 'Machine']).sum()
fdr2 = fdr.unstack('Time')
fdr2
```

This is my code:

```
import dash_table_experiments
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import dash_table_experiments as dash_table
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import plotly_express as px
import plotly.offline as pyo

dff3 = pd.read_csv('df3.csv', encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False)
dff3
fdr = dff3.groupby(['Time', 'Machine']).sum()
fdr2 = fdr.unstack('Time')
fdr2

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([ 

dcc.Graph(
        id = 'GrapGo',
        figure = {
            'data' : [
                go.Scatter(

                x = fdr2.index,
                y = fdr2.loc[rowname],
                mode = "markers+lines",
                name = rowname
                )for rowname in fdr2.index


            ],
            'layout' : go.Layout(
                title = "Grafico com go",
                xaxis = {'title': 'X Label'},
                yaxis = {'title': 'y Label'}

            )
        }
    )

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

This is the graph I'm getting:

[image]

The expected result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see in your questions there is a need to run the server. If you just need to produce a plot then this code would do the job (Dash v1.6.0):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Machine': ['K2K01','K2K01','K2K01','K2K02','K2K02','K2K02','K2K03','K2K03','K2K03'],
                   'Units': [100,200,400,400,300,100,500,700,500],
                   'Time':[11,12,13,11,12,13,11,12,13]})

groups = df.groupby(by='Machine')

data = []
colors=['red', 'blue', 'green']

for group, dataframe in groups:
    dataframe = dataframe.sort_values(by=['Time'])
    trace = go.Scatter(x=dataframe.Time.tolist(), 
                       y=dataframe.Units.tolist(),
                       marker=dict(color=colors[len(data)]),
                       name=group)
    data.append(trace)

layout =  go.Layout(xaxis={'title': 'Time'},
                    yaxis={'title': 'Produced Units'},
                    margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 50, 'r': 50},
                    hovermode='closest')

figure = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)  
figure.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Tony. No problem with the server, i can adopt to run in the server, my doubt was about how create and append more efficient these traces. Thank you so much my friend. Have a nice day.

Comment: This is an old one, but one comment: Is all that duplication of Machine and Time values really necessary, or is there a way to set those categories only once? When you have large data sets, it feels wrong to duplicate thousand of items.